# Reinstall Samsung Stock Apps

Tags: root-access, 4.4-kitkat, samsung-galaxy-s-4, factory-reset, samsung-galaxy-gear

A few months earlier, I got a Samsung Galaxy S4. Immediately I rooted it and used NoBloat to unistall some stock apps. One of those apps was Gear Manager, since I didn't plan to get one at the time, and if I did I'd just reinstall it from Samsung Apps.

I just got a Gear 2 and installed Gear Manager. When I launched the app it states that my device is incompatible (even though it is).

This leads me to believe that the package I uninstalled was a daemon or helper for the app to manage my Gear with. If so, then where can I get the APK for the daemon.

P.S.: Factory reset is an unviable option as I can't backup Google Authenticator, therefore I'd lose access to multiple online accounts.

P.P.S.: Software update is also impossible as I'd lose my root access.

EDIT: If anyone has a rooted Galaxy S4, please give me a NoBloat backup.

EDIT: Well, I just uninstalled Samsung Apps Package for Gear Manager, rebooted the phone and apparantly it works now. It looks like the preinstalled Samsung apps work like the Google apps, they both have a base package already installed, but updates and the like are distributed as patches.

Comment: Side-note: Even if a factory-reset would be "viable", it wouldn't bring back any of the removed files. Those where stored on `/system`, which isn't touched at all by a factory-reset.

Comment: @lzzy I did not know that. I thought a factory reset was: Download latest OTA update, delete everything in flash (except the update package), apply update, reboot. Thanks for preventing another headache.

Comment: You might wish to consult our [factory-reset tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/factory-reset/info) :) Hint: Many of our tag-wikis contain useful background information, even first-aid (if applicable). Always a good idea to check them first. Click a tag, then select the "info" link/tab. Factory reset just "empties" `/data` and `/cache`, basically – i.e. "undoes" all changes a "normal" user (without root) might have done to the device, thus restoring factory default *configuration*. It always assumes no changes have been done to read-only areas such as `/system`.

Comment: Is it out of your league to try and find a stock /system dump from sites like [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com) and extract your desired APKs from there?

Comment: @aureljared Good idea, though Gear support was added in November 2013 and for some reason I can only find March 2013 builds on the internet. Would you mind pointing me to a more recent build?

Comment: @manuel.rivera [Help yourself.](http://live.samsung-updates.com/index.php?device=GT-I9500)

Comment: Be sure to download the correct one.

Comment: @aureljared None of the ROMs on the site have the same hardware version (L720) as mine. Though, after a bit of googling I found that L720 is a Sprint modified ROM. So I should be able to use a ROM from that site, right? Also, do I need to use my region code (VP), or can I get away with using a ROM from another region?

Comment: Should've said you had a Sprint S4. Haha but you can find ROMs for that [here.](http://live.samsung-updates.com/index.php?device=SPH-L720)